# Hyperledger-fabric : chaincode deploy connection error

Tags: go, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying to test fabric chaincode example02, with docker. I'm newbie :)

This is my `docker-compose.yml` :

```
membersrvc:
  image: hyperledger/fabric-membersrvc
  command: membersrvc

vp0:
  image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
  environment:
    - CORE_PER_ID=vp0
    - CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
    - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=http://0.0.0.0:2375
    - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
  command: sh -c "sleep 5; peer node start --peer-chaincodedev"

vp1:
  extends:
    service: vp0
  environment:
    - CORE_PEER_ID=vp1
    - CORE_PEER_DISCOVERY_ROOTNODE=vp0:7051
  links:
    - vp0

vp2:
  extends:
    service: vp0
  environment:
    - CORE_PEER_ID=vp2
    - CORE_PEER_DISCOVERY_ROOTNODE=vp0:7051
  links:
    - vp0
```

and I run (I refered to [Fabric chaincode setup page](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Setup/Chaincode-setup/#vagrant)):

Terminal 1 :

`$ docker-compose up`

Terminal 2 :

`$ cd /hyperledger/examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example02`

`$ CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=mycc CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051 ./chaincode_example02`

Terminal 3 :

`$ peer chaincode deploy -n mycc -c '{"Args": ["init", "a","100", "b", "200"]}'`

It works well in terminal 1,2. But terminal 3 shows connection error.

```
2016/10/21 04:39:15 grpc: addrConn.resetTransport failed to create client
transport: connection error: desc = "transport: dial tcp 0.0.0.0:7051:
getsockopt: connection refused"; Reconnecting to {"0.0.0.0:7051" <nil>}
Error: Error building chaincode: Error trying to connect to local peer: 
grpc: timed out when dialing
```

What's the problem?

Comment: which version of fabric are you using ?

Comment: @SufiyanGhori Maybe latest. I used this command for download :
 `git clone ssh://LFID@gerrit.hyperledger.org:29418/fabric && scp -p -P 29418 LFID@gerrit.hyperledger.org:hooks/commit-msg fabric/.git/hooks/`

Comment: @SufiyanGhori `git branch` shows only `master`.
`git log` shows that `4b53c7c04b8502de108040ef4ff81f4de0d257d2` is top latest.

Comment: @SufiyanGhori Thank you for your replies.

(1) I tried to pull the latest updates and it showed same error.
(2) I used your example code, it worked but showed another error in Terminal 3.
`Error: Error building chaincode: rpc error: code = 2 desc = Error getting chaincode package bytes: Cannot generate hashcode from empty chaincode path`

I'm trying to find the solution now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are missing the compose statements to map the required ports from the docker container to the host machine (where you are trying out the peer command ). So its possible that the peer process is listening on port 7051 inside your peer docker container, but this connection is not available to the peer command used outside of this container in terminal 3.

You can map ports using the 'ports' tag. eg:

```
membersrvc:
  image: hyperledger/fabric-membersrvc
  ports:
    - "7054:7054"
  command: membersrvc

vp0:
  image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
  ports:
    - "7050:7050"
    - "7051:7051"
    - "7053:7053"
  environment:
    - CORE_PER_ID=vp0
    - CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
    - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=http://0.0.0.0:2375
    - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
  command: sh -c "sleep 5; peer node start --peer-chaincodedev"
```

Before you do `peer chaincode deploy ...`in terminal 3, you can check if a the peer process is listening on port 7051 using

```
netstat -lnptu |grep 7051
```